# WinForms/WebForms controls' default case musings

Tags: c#, winforms, webforms, uppercase, lowercase

Why does the WinForms default name for controls start with lowercase, but is uppercase for WebForms?  What's the likely rationale for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably lost to the depths of time, and an artifact of different teams working on different designers.

This next note doesn't apply to the original days, but one interesting point in the current incarnation of ASP.NET is that the page *inherits* from the code-behind, so the proper-case names would make sense *if* they were exposed as protected properties. But they aren't: they are exposed as protected fields... so that is 2 standard guidelines broken at once (non-private fields and casing of fields).